# Android 1.6 Browser List box HTML element

Tags: html, android, browser, listbox

Is it possible that the Android browser renders the HTML list box, such as:

item 1
    item 2
    item 3
    item 4
    All

as a dropdown? I can't seem to get it to display a proper multiline listbox. Anyone knows what the trick is?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out that this just is not possible, Android browser does not render listboxes the standard way but its own way.